# jQuery Mobile in Phonegap, Android, dropdown under panel

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

Did anyone come across the issue of bleeding dropdown menu through panel? It happens only with dropdown, normal button is fine. 
Basically the panel hides the dropdown menubut it can still be clicked.

I'm using Phonegap and Android, haven't had a chance to test in on iPhone.

here is panel:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="panel-tools" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a" data-position="right">
...
```

and the dropdown:

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div class="ui-block-a"><select name="select-axis-x" id="axis-x" data-mini="true"></select></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><select name="select-axis-y" id="axis-y" data-mini="true"></select></div>           
                <div class="ui-block-c"><a data-role="button" href="#" id="reload-graph" data-mini="true">RELOAD</a></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What is a bleeding dropdown menu through panel to you?

Comment: when I click on the panel on the space where the dropdown is under the click is fired as the panel wasn't on top of it.

Comment: So when you click on a select box click event is falling through to the panel?

Comment: yeah that's pretty much what it is.